# Simple Todo app

Tags: javascript, angular.js, to-do-list

I'm writing a todo app as a test. Having never done Ionic nor Angular apps before, I am not sure if I am following best practices here.

What I have done is try to keep my controllers thin by placing all persistant logic in the model (service?). And instead of hard coding links in the view, I am calling a function in the controller.

Are there any other things I should or shouldn't be doing?

```
// controllers

angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('TodosCtrl', function($scope, Todos, $state) {

  $scope.todos = Todos.all();

  $scope.data = {
    showDelete: false
  };

  $scope.add = function() {
    $state.go('tab.add');
  };

  $scope.remove = function(todo) {
    Todos.remove(todo);
  };
})

.controller('TodoDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Todos, $state) {

  $scope.todo = Todos.get($stateParams.todoId);

  $scope.remove = function(todo) {
    Todos.remove(todo);
    $state.go('tab.todos');
  };
})

.controller('TodoAddCtrl', function ($scope, $state, Todos) {
  $scope.content = {};

  $scope.add = function() {

    var todo = $scope.content.name;

    if(todo) {

      $scope.content.name = '';

      Todos.add({
        id: Todos.all().length + 1,
        name: todo
      });

      $state.go('tab.todos');
    }
  };

})

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  // unused for now
  $scope.settings = {
    enableServer: true
  };
})



// services

angular.module('starter.services', ['ngStorage'])

.factory ('StorageService', function ($localStorage) {

  $localStorage = $localStorage.$default({
    todos: []
  });

  var _getAll = function () {
    return $localStorage.todos;
  };
  var _add = function (todo) {
    $localStorage.todos.push(todo);
  }
  var _remove = function (todo) {
    $localStorage.todos.splice($localStorage.todos.indexOf(todo), 1);
  }
  return {
    getAll: _getAll,
    add: _add,
    remove: _remove
  };
})

.factory('Todos', function(StorageService) {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array
  var todos = StorageService.getAll();

  return {
    all: function() {
      return todos;
    },
    remove: function(todo) {
      StorageService.remove(todo);
    },
    add: function(todo) {
      StorageService.add(todo);
    },
    get: function(todoId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
        if (todos[i].id === parseInt(todoId)) {
          return todos[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **Angular Best Practices** (or very good practice) take a look at John Papa's Style Guide:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

It is well written, easy to understand, includes examples and really helps in development!

---

Now to your code.

### Files

In an actual application, you would put every single module, controller, service, and directive into a seperate file and name it accordingly.
Basically, everytime you write `angular.module`, `angular.controller`, [...], it's a new file! This might seem ridiculously at first, but in a big project, it really helps to find stuff. A build chain, e.g. Gulp, will later put everything back together and even optimize it.

### Controller vs Services

You want the controller to have anything regarding the view. It includes callbacks (for ng-clicks e.g.) and maybe some logic that is very specific to the view. In the end, it is just a controller and just controlls what should happen and what the view should be able to use.
Use a service/factory for all the real application logic. Everything that might be reusable gets a own service. Get data from the server? Service. Calculate something based on the user input? If it might be used somewhere else too, create a service! (`GreatService.calculate(userInput)`) This way you not only can use it again, but it also really helps you to test your logic in unit tests.

In your specific Todo Example:
I think you might have used too many controllers here. I dont's see your template, but this would be probably just fine with one controller and your service. Unless this has multiply states?

Take a look at John Papa's style guide, it's worth !
By the way, using $scope is not recommended. It does work, but is still a thing from the beginnings of Angular. Check this out: https://johnpapa.net/do-you-like-your-angular-controllers-with-or-without-sugar/

Comment: The todo has 3 controllers. The list, detail and add page. I followed the same practice as the default tab template (`ionic start myApp`).